# Direct all traffic to root index page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Is it possible to add code to the root htaccess file of a site, to direct all traffic to the main index page for the site?  For example, if someone goes to any of the following URLs, they they should be redirected to example.com:

- subdomain.example.com
- example.com/directory

Comment: What is `DocumentRoot` for `subdomain.example.com` in `VirtualHost`?

Comment: example.com/subdomain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use these rules in site root .htaccess of `example.com`:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(?:jpe?g|gif|png|ico|tiff|css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^index\.html$ /index.html [L,NC,R]
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the suggestion.  Should I change the .php to be .html if the site only has html files?

Comment: This is unfortunately not working for me.  I tried:

`DirectoryIndex index.html`
`RewriteEngine On`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`
`RewriteRule !^index\.html$ index.html [L,NC]`

Comment: When going to example.com/directory/index.html it does not redirect

Comment: That worked as far as not allowing a user to reach a different page; however, images on the index page stopped loading (perhaps because the URL of the image isn't allowed to be loaded).  On a different note, when loading example.com/directory it loads example.com/index.html but the URL in the browser window is example.com/directory

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't working.  I'm getting a browser error message saying that the page has been redirected too many times and cannot load.  I tried in Chrome and Edge.

Comment: That didn't work either.  The looping stopped, but now if I go to example.com/directory/directory the browser lists all of the files in that directory instead of redirecting

Comment: I'm going to see if there's something in the example.com/directory's .htaccess file that's causing the issue in that directory

Comment: This .htaccess must be placed in site root not inside the `directory/`. Also there must not be another .htaccess in your system and this rule should be your topmost rule.

Comment: The issue was that there was an .htaccess file in the other folder as well.  Once I overwrote those settings your code worked.  Thanks very much!

Comment: Wouldn't you rather have it redirect to / instead of index.html? / is probably better for SEO than  index.html